# service list in Docker Desktop for Windows

Tags: minikube, docker-desktop, kubernetes-service

Is there an equivalent command of ***minikube service list*** in Docker Desktop for Windows?

https://medium.com/swlh/kubernetes-services-part-1-399a0dd05211

Answer (score 0):

A Kubernetes Service is an abstraction which defines a logical set of Pods and a policy by which to access them - sometimes called a micro-service. You can use services for cross-operating system connectivity. In Windows, services can utilize the following types, properties and capabilities:

- Service Environment variables
- NodePort
- ClusterIP
- LoadBalancer
- ExternalName
- Headless services

Here is the [documentation](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1mPuHECvmyKms_kc8TP7zLDMxN9AUfBXhbdJcmlasdVg/edit#) that lists all the services of kubernetes in windows desktop.

Try using this command to expose service with type:Nodeport

```
PS C:\> .\kubectl.exe expose deployment hello-nginx --type=NodePort
```

service "hello-nginx" exposed

This [documentation](https://rominirani.com/tutorial-getting-started-with-kubernetes-on-your-windows-laptop-with-minikube-3269b54a226) has more detailed information on exposing the service and scaling the service in windows desktop.